# getting a node's value from XML file in TestComplete

Tags: xml, automated-tests, testcomplete

My XML file's structure is like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"xmlns:core="http://x.y.com/xy/xyz">
<atom:title>TestTitle</atom:title>
<atom:link rel="a" href="$a_u"/>
<atom:link rel="ot" href="$ou"/>
<atom:link rel="db" type="app/c.d.p+xml" href="e.xml">
  <atom:inline>
   <payload xmlns="http://www.yyy.com/xxx" model="https://xxxx.yyy.com/api/te/db/et/r1">
     <field name="asset.title">
       <value>DP</value>
     </field>
     <field>
      <value>xxx</value>
     </field>
     |
     |
     |
  </atom:inline>
 </atom:link>
</atom:entry>
```

I am trying to get the value `DP` of filed whose `name="asset.title"`

Followed this Doc's and tried but no luck..

http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/57106/

http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/58850/

**How can i get this value. Thanks in advance for any pointer or help.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify selection namespaces when dealing with an XML that has namespaces defined. The following script should work for you.

```
function test()
{
  var fileName = "c:\\test.xml";
  var doc = Sys.OleObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
  doc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:ns='http://www.yyy.com/xxx'");
  doc.load(fileName);

  var value = doc.selectSingleNode("/atom:entry/atom:inline/ns:payload/ns:field[@name='asset.title']/ns:value").text;
  Log.Message(value);
}
```